# How do I parse the following nested object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, nested

I have a JSON object containing another JSON object like below, the size of which is not fixed. I need to access the values in the inner object.

```
myObj = {
"name" : "XYZ",
"sex" : "F",
"questions" : {"1":"testquestion1", "2":"testquestion2", "3":"testquestion3"}
}
```

I need a way to extract the `[testquestion1,testquestion2,testquestion3]` using a loop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag, especially what is in all-capitals. It is confusing to use the term JSON for something that is actually JavaScript code. "JSON" is used for the text data exchange format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a loop, you can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
let myObj = {
"name" : "XYZ",
"sex" : "F",
"questions" : {"1":"testquestion1", "2":"testquestion2", "3":"testquestion3"}
}

let result = Object.values(myObj.questions);

console.log(result);
```